# Array of strings initialization

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

This piece of code swap the first and last element of a given array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* swap first and last element of array */
void fn(void *v, size_t length, size_t size)
{
    char *a = (char *)v;
    char *b = (char *)v + size * (length - 1);
    char temp;

    do {
        temp = *a;
        *a++ = *b;
        *b++ = temp;
    } while (--size > 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {0, 1, 2};
    double b[] = {0., 1., 2.};
    char c[][15] = {"Hello", ",", "this is a test"};

    fn(a, 3, sizeof(a[0]));
    fn(b, 3, sizeof(b[0]));
    fn(c, 3, sizeof(c[0]));
    printf("%d %d\n", a[0], a[2]);
    printf("%f %f\n", b[0], b[2]);
    printf("%s %s\n", c[0], c[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2 0
2.000000 0.000000
this is a test Hello
```

My question is:

The code is safe?, it is guaranteed that `c[0]` is initialized by the compiler as

`{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

or `c[0]` may contain `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0, [garbage]}`?

**EDIT**:
And if `c` is not initialized?

```
int main(void)
{
    char c[3][15];

    strcpy(c[0], "Hello");
    strcpy(c[1], ",");
    strcpy(c[2], "this is a test");
    fn(c, 3, sizeof(c[0]));
    printf("%s %s\n", c[0], c[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it safe to use `fn`? (`c[0]` contains 9 bytes of garbage)

Comment: copying garbage wouldn't make that piece of code unsafe, as long as you don't need certain values behind NUL after swapping

Comment: Ingo, this is my question! so copying garbage (if any) is not a problem?

Comment: no, you can copy whatever ther arrays may contain. Nevertheless, it would be interesting to know which answer is correct

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt: If the memory would not have been initialised (what however is not the fact here), accessing it (in terms of reading it) would provoke undefined behaviour!

Comment: @alk, undefined behaviour if `c` is not initialized and elements are filled using `strcpy`, right? (excuse my poor english)

Comment: In C reading a value which had not been initialises before (either explicit or implicit) provokes undefined behaviour. Example: `void foo(void) { int a, b; a = b; ...` provokes UB as `b` is read without having been initialised before.

Comment: @alk I have found [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219971/read-before-write-is-undefined-with-malloced-memory]) and ouah's answer which would tell me it's not UB for `char *`. It's about malloc() instead of automatic variables but does that make a difference?

Comment: Huu ... I love exception ... ;-> - however I'd go for *R..*'s comment on *ouah*'s answer.

Comment: There is an edit, thank you guys!!

Comment: From the C11-Standard's Annex J.2 "Undefined behavior": "*The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate*" So I'd say your update's use of `fn()` provokes UB for `c`'s 1st and 2nd element.

Comment: However, the 1st rule to write robust and secure code is: "Always properly initialise all variables."

Comment: @alk, thank you again and thanks for the rule, wow then this [qsort implementation of glibc](http://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/qsort.c.html) can invoke UB if `c` is not initialized.

Comment: Cool! :-) However the answer by *ouah* you linked above along with *R..*'s comment on it, somehow reveals an ambiguity in the C-Standard . I have no idea if "C99, 6.2.6.1p5" beats its "Annex J.2" or the other way round.

Comment: Wouldn't this only invoke UB, if array's won't be fully initialised when being passed to `qsort()`?

Comment: It was, if we replaced `fn()` by `qsort()` in **EDIT**'s `main()`. I would have never have thought about that (and to be honest, I still wouldn't be too afraid if I saw it tomorrow in my code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the C11-Standard chapter 6.7.9:

> 21 If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration

So yes, `c[0]` will be fully initialised.

This was also defined by the C99-Standard (chapter 6.7.8/21). For ealier versions of the standard I don't know this (anymore ... ;-)).

Comment: Do you know if that has been defined like that for older standards as well?

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

> it is guaranteed that `c[0]` is initialized by the compiler as
>
> ```
> {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

Yes, the language guarantees that. It zero-initializes the elements of the array that are not explicitly initialized.