# C unrelated function seems to affect simple array initialization

Tags: c

I am seeing some really weird behavior in my C project - https://github.com/ryu577/base/blob/master/numerical/c/NumericalRecipiesCode/src/ch05/tst5.c

On line 77, I run one of the routines on "testFn" which is on line 13 and I have also included below. I do this by passing a pointer to the function.

```
float testFn(float x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

Next, on line 87, I simply attempt to initialize a 1d array of floats based on a boilerplate routine from Numerical recipes in C:

```
float *c1; c1 = vector(0, n1);
```

The "vector" function is quite simple and included here:

```
float *vector(long nl, long nh)
/* allocate a float vector with subscript range v[nl..nh] */
{
    float *v;
    v=(float *)malloc((size_t) ((nh-nl+1+NR_END)*sizeof(float)));
    if (!v) nrerror("allocation failure in vector()");
    return v-nl+NR_END;
}
```

Now, when I print the entries in my "vector" (float array - c1), this is what I get -

```
12.00   12.00   12.00   0.00    0.00
```

Somehow, it decides to put 12s in the first 3 positions. But what is really interesting is that these numbers depend on how I define testFn. For example, if I define it as:

```
float testFn(float x)
{
    return x*x*x;
}
```

I then get the entries of c1:

```
112.00  110.04  109.04  108.53  0.00
```

But the thing is that the creation and initialization of the vector had nothing to do with testFn at all. So, how is it able to influence its values in this way? Is it related to some block of memory that isn't being freed up and the values are spilling over into the new array?

Comment: It doesn't look like you *initialised* a vector - you just *allocated* it. Its contents are undefined until you store something there. Trying to read these values prior to initialising them is UB.

Comment: Also, please take note of comments and suggestions on your previous questions - especially the advice that you typically need to provide a [mcve] if you want people to help you.

Comment: @PaulR - thanks. I found it very hard to provide a minimal example here since any part of the code could have been causing this behavior. I understand that I haven't initialized the vector now, but still curious as to why testFn is able to influence the default values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc()` will **not initialize** the contents of the array. This means in this block could be anything - floats, ints or complete garbage, in your case it's some numerical value thats left from a previous operation. This will also happen when declaring an array inside of a function.

You usually don't want to waste compute time on clearing every single allocated block, because you'll be overwriting them anyway when using them. To get the desired behavior use a loop to initialize the array after allocating it.

Finally, note that your program may invoke undefined behaviour by reading uninitialized memory as `float`. See question [read before write is undefined with malloced memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219971/read-before-write-is-undefined-with-malloced-memory) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Okay, good to know this is expected behavior. I'm used to C# and Java where these kinds of things never happen.

Comment: You could also use `calloc()`instead, i recommend reading the man pages for malloc and calloc first though.

Comment: `calloc()` just zeros out the memory which might work for integers or but not necessarily for floating point variables.

Comment: @RohitPandey: Then, welcome to C! In C, many things can happen (or not) that would never happen in C# and Java. That was actually one of the main motivations for creating these languages. You should really read up on "undefined behaviour" in C.

Comment: @sleske: Thanks, will do. If you have any particular article in mind regarding the subject, let me know.

Comment: @alk: It may work for floating point, but it is not guaranteed by the C standard. I think it will (happen to) work on most common platforms, though.

Comment: @RohitPandey: There's a good blog article (three actually) on the LLVM blog: [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html). The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is also a good start.

Comment: To clarify: The man page states `calloc()` will write zeros to the allocated *bits*. This means it will work for any type that defines zero to actually be zero (which [float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Examples) and int both do) - and that it's necessary to know what a byte full of zeros means for your data type.

Comment: @MaximilianSchlosser: _nitpick mode on_ According to the C standard, all bits zero is indeed 0 for `int` and `unsigned int`. There is no such guarantee for `float`. IEEE 754 does give that guarantee; however, the C standard does not say a `float` must be in IEEE 754 format (though many compilers use it).